# How to modify the value of "readstring.indexOf()"?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to change, for example, `readstring.indexOf("xx")` to `readstring.indexOf("")`. It is something like this: `readstring.indexOf("xx") = readstring.indexOf("")` but this kind isn't impossible.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you please provide more context in your question?

Comment: Why would you want the index of the empty string?  It doesn't make any sense.  As well, your second line is trying to assign a value to a function.

Comment: Can you give some background on the problem you're trying to solve?  The way you've laid it out makes it seem like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was in an appointment ...
But it is this:
I'm doing a project that involves the arduino ethernet shield and in the webpage that is generated, I want to implement a single button to trigger two lamps alternately, ie press once, turn on lamp 1; press again, turn off this lamp; press again, turn on the lamp 2; press again, turn off this lamp ... and if you press the button again, lamp 1 will light again and so on ...

Comment: But on this page there will also be a refresh every 3 seconds to display the current values ​​of a sensor of temperature. The problem is that every click on the button causes the 'tag' of the button to appear at the end of the page's address, for example: "/ btn1" (at the end of the web page url).

Comment: This is the tag that should be deleted each time I click the button, otherwise, while I will not click on another button (which is not what I want), the tag stays there causing each page refresh, the bulbs also go off and on without user intervention. I tried to create a button whose tag is ("") and when I click the bulbs button and (before 3 seconds) I also click on this new button, it works correctly! Ie the bulbs do not come on automatically.

Comment: So in reality there are two solutions to my problem:
1 - Get a code (preferably in html / javascript) that when pressing the bulb button, the button that clears the tag will also be activated soon thereafter;
2 - Get assign "" to readstring.indexof ().